# How can I nest <Router> (not <Route>) - or, how to declare <Route>s in external file?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a large React application that will have multiple, complex modules. These modules are usually addressed by the first part of the URL, like so:

```
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={AppFrame}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="journal" component={Journal} />
        <Route path="map" component={MapComponent} />
        <Route path="import" component={Importer} />
        <Route path="plants" component={PlantsBaseData} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
```

Here, there are four "modules": `/journal`, `/map`, `/import`, `/plants`.

Each module is wrapped by a HOC that implements *lazy loading*, so the JavaScript code implementing the component (for example, `Journal`) is **loaded on-demand**.

Now some modules, like the `PlantsBaseData` component allow to navigate database records and I'd like an URL like `/plants/:id`.

Is there any way to declare such a route *within* `PlantsBaseData`
 - that is, in an external JavaScript "file" that is not yet loaded when the root `<Router>` initializes?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to be allowed:

```
const PlantsBaseData = () => {
  <SomeUIComponent>
    <AnotherUIComponent>
      <div>...</div>
    </AnotherUIComponent>
    <Router>
     <IndexRoute component={Hints} />
     <Route path=":id" component={PlantForm} />
    </Router>
  <SomeUIComponent>
};
```

...because `<Router>` expects a mandatory `history` property (but it wouldn't make much sense to set it again here). Also, using `<Route>` without a direct `<Router>` parent doesn't work either.

How can this be done?

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, you might be interested in the work being done on React Router 4.  It's still in early alpha stages, but they're working on doing just what you're looking for.  Specifically, the new `Match` component will allow route rendering within your component instead of predefining all of your routes in one place.  Here's a quick start guide, https://react-router.now.sh/quick-start.  Barring that there's no way to embed routing inside a component using React Router v2, not sure about v3 which is in beta.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said

> *(but it wouldn't make much sense to set it again here)*

It wouldn't make sense when you try to nest `<Router>`. An app should have only one router. Inside which you can have multiple routes. To solve your problem, you can try the following.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={AppFrame}>
    <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
    <Route path="journal" component={Journal} />
    <Route path="map" component={MapComponent} />
    <Route path="import" component={Importer} />
    <Route path="plants" component={PlantsBaseData}> 
      <Route path="/:id" component={yourComponent} />
    <Route/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Here you're nesting `<Route />` instead of the `<Router />`, which is not possible.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that I must define all routes in one place. That's especially problematic because `yourComponent` (just like `PlantsBaseData`) is only loaded when the `plants/` route is active. To be more specific, `PlantsBaseData` is a "higher order" component that loads the real `PlantsBaseData` component once mounted.